# Color of masked values in healpy

Tags: python, healpy

Is there a way to change the color of masked value when masking a healpy mask? Is there a way to make the map more aesthetic? Right now it just drops grey pixels on the map where the values are masked.

The code I use is

```
masked_map = np.zeros(len(vr))
masked_map[(vr > 0)] = 1
influx = (0.3*rvir)**2*rho*vr

m = hp.ma(influx)
m.mask = masked_map

hp.mollview(hp.smoothing(m, sigma=0.1))
hp.graticule()
```

vr, rho are some quantities pixelized according to HEALpix rules. The result is
[image]

Comment: Please show us some about are you trying.

Comment: You should post here the code that you tried and the errors that it is producing. Write in more detail.

Comment: @JuanAntonio I have added a code and a picture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mollview: use matplotlib colormaps and change background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023932/mollview-use-matplotlib-colormaps-and-change-background-color)